# Can't cast result of Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() to ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

On the `ThreadPoolExecutor` docs, [(here)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), it says to use the Executors class to create common threads, I want to only have one thread, so I use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor` and cast it to `ThreadPoolExecutor` as I have seen other examples do, but this throws a `java.lang.ClassCastException`.
Here is the minimalised code I have reproduced it with.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, I would always look for some kind of contract definition before making such an expectation. The docs do not clearly say that the `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` will return `ThreadPoolExecutor` type object. 
Moreover, such implementation (without the contract) could potentially be changed in the future.

In this case `newSingleThreadExecutor()` returns a `ExecutorService` which underneath is a `ThreadPoolExecutor` but wrapped in a 
`FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService`. This class is more or less a sibling of `ThreadPoolExecutor` and as such, cannot be cast to it.
I guess it's done so that:

> the returned executor is guaranteed not to be reconfigurable to use additional threads

Depending on what you want to achieve, you should consider either:
- using `ExecutorService` returned from `newSingleThreadExecutor()` instead of `ThreadPoolExecutor`;
- using `newFixedThreadPool(1)` to get `ThreadPoolExecutor`.